# running jquery script in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am learning about css,jquery etc.

I thought this code would remove the border around the words "haha", but it does not.

```
<head>
    <style>
        div.errorMessages {
            padding: 8px 8px 0 8px;
            font: bold 11px/14px Arial,sans-serif;
            color: #B22222;
            border: 2px solid; 
            border-radius: 25px;
        } 
    </style>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<div class=errorMessages>
    haha
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready($function() {
        $(div class="errorMessages").removeAttr("border");
    });
</script>
```

does a script "refresh" the browser page completely?

Any help on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of issues here, firstly the selector should be a string. It follows the same rules as selecting in CSS so yours should be:

```
$('.errorMessages')
```

Secondly, `removeAttr()` is used to remove an attribute on an element, whereas you're trying to amend the CSS, so need to use `css()` instead. To remove a `border` in CSS, set it to `0` or `none`.

Then you don't need the `$` in front of the anonymous function in the DOMReady handler, and you're also missing the `body` element.

Putting it all together, try this

```
<head>
    <style>
        div.errorMessages {
            padding: 8px 8px 0 8px;
            font: bold 11px/14px Arial,sans-serif;
            color: #B22222;
            border: 2px solid; 
            border-radius: 25px;
        } 
    </style>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="errorMessages">
        haha
    </div>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.errorMessages').css('border', '0');
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

I would strongly suggest you familiarise yourself with the [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com) as it covers the basics very well.

Comment: $('.errorMessages').css('border','0'); removes "haha" and the border too.    I  want to remove only the border but keep the words.

Answer (score 0):

Directly use `$(".errorMessages").css("border","0");`

Mind that you are not implementing border using attributes, its the CSS that is doing it.

Other thing is put `<div class="errorMessages">` , just to avoid errors.